# Walmart API Error: WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE set null or invalid

Tags: e-commerce, walmart-api

My client has a Walmart marketplace store and we are trying figure out how to successfully make the Walmart API's `Multiple Item Inventory for All Ship Nodes API call`.

The API production URL is :
`https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/inventories`

The purpose of this call is getting the inventory of the store using the API.

Unfortunately, we are stuck because we don't know what value to put for `WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE`.

As a result, the API response is unsuccessful and gives this error:

```
{
    "error": [
        {
            "code": "INVALID_REQUEST_HEADER.GMP_GATEWAY_API",
            "field": "WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE",
            "description": "WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE set null or invalid",
            "info": "One or more request headers are invalid.",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "category": "DATA",
            "causes": [],
            "errorIdentifiers": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Where can the value of WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE be found?

Comment: WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE (required) [string]
A unique ID to track the consumer request by channel. Use the Consumer Channel Type received during onboarding,

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue. I had to open a ticket with support to get the `WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE`.

Just an FYI, this didn't solve the problem as the value they gave us still resulted in the API returning the same error code.

Comment: What is this a string value that you could share with all of us or a string unique to the account?

Comment: @rom it appears to be account specific (maybe category specific?) I found other WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE's on the web and tried all of those values--none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you integrating with Walmart APIs directly?
Please use your consumer ID as the WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE API header.

Integrating through a Solution Provider?
The Solution Provider should use their own value for the header, which they can get by opening a case with Partner Support.